# Returning substring of string after first occurence of a comma

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, csv

How can I take this input CSV file:

```
0,1
1,2
3,4
5,6,7
8,10
9,10
```

and return only the substring of each line after the first occurrence of "," so that my output is:

```
1
2
4
6,7
10
10
```

I can only figure out how to parse the string within a certain range after splitting by commas, so I am using `string.split(",")[1]` to return everything after the first comma and before the next comma but I can't figure out how to get everything after the first comma.  So for the inputs with more than one comma, I'm missing data.

Comment: I can only figure out how to parse the string within a certain range after splitting by commas, so I have string.split(",")[1] to return everything after the first comma and before the next comma but I can't figure out how to get everything after the first comma

Comment: How are you reading this file in Java code?

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
line.substring(line.indexOf(",")+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways of removing everything before the first occurrence of a `,`.

1. Find the index (position) of the first `,` and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) using that index.

This would look like

```
String wantedPart = lineOfText.substring(lineOfText.indexOf(",") + 1);
```

Since `indexOf` returns the index of the `,` itself, you need to add one to get everything past it.

---

2. Use a better overload like [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).  This overload allows you to match a maximum of `limit` substrings.  So with a limit of 2 results, it will split on the first `,` found and leave everything else in the second (final) element of the result array.

In your code, you could use

```
String wantedPart = lineOfText.split(",", 2)[1];
```

Comment: 2. is not correct. According to the manual: Limiter 'If provided, splits the string at each occurrence of the specified separator, but stops when limit entries have been placed in the array. Any leftover text is not included in the array at all."

Comment: @Raj I fixed a typo, but you are mistaken. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) linked in my answer, which states (emphasis mine) "If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, **and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.**" Are you looking at a different version?

Comment: Whoops! I had a brain fart, I thought this was a javascript question.

Answer (score 1):

If a shell script will do, you can use the `cut` command:

`-d ','` means use a comma as `-f2-` means use fields 2 onwards.

```
Machine:~ donald$ cat file.txt
0,1
1,2
3,4
5,6,7
8,10
9,10
Machine:~ donald$ cat file.txt | cut -d ',' -f2-
1
2
4
6,7
10
10
Machine:~ donald$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try String.indexOf(",") and so on.